# matlab single() function in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I try to convert matlab code to python/numpy code.

I have this line:

```
l = single(l)
```

"l" is a array of arrays and as the matlab docu says "Convert to single precision".

How can I do that with numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a two-dimensional numpy array to single-precision, use `astype` and give it the `float32` argument. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1.], [2.], [3.]])
>>> a
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.]])
>>> a = a.astype('float32')
>>> a
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.]], dtype=float32)
```

For more about numeric and array data types, see [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).